# List check that elements are different

Tags: prolog

I would like to write a predicate different_from(Xs,X) which is a check that succeeds if and only if X is different from all the elements of the list Xs.

So the query

```
different_from([3,2,5],4)
```

should succeed but this following query should fail:

```
different_from([3,2,5],2)
```

Since the predicate is a check it should not instantiate either of its arguments.

thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: `different_from(Xs, X) :- maplist(dif(X), Xs).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple rule consisting of two clauses:

- The first clause says that `different_from` is successful when the list is empty,
- The second clause says that `different_from` is successful when the first element of the list does not match the element being searched, and also when `different_from` for the tail is successful as well.

Here is the same thing written in Prolog syntax:

```
different_from([], _).
different_from([H|T], E) :- E \= H, different_from(T, E).
```